# Conan and gRPC: Undefined references to various `gpr_` symbols

Tags: c++, grpc, conan

This is an issue with using gRPC with Conan in my project.
In short, I have a gRPC based project, and my dependencies are:

```
    requires = (
        "predictions-algorithms/15.16.51@navassist/testing",
        "grpc/1.20.0@inexorgame/stable",
        "protobuf/3.6.1@bincrafters/stable",
        "protoc_installer/3.6.1@bincrafters/stable"
    )
```

However, at the end of the linking process of the project, a bunch of messages appear about undefined references to various gpr_* symbols in libgrpc.a.

I checked with `readelf -Ws my/package/path/to/libgrpc.a | grep gpr_(some symbol)`, and, sure enough, all those symbols are undefined in there.

I also opened the issue at the [repository](https://github.com/inexorgame/conan-grpc/issues/20) of gRPC package I use above.

No idea what to do next... Any help is welcome.

Comment: These seem to be defined in a separate libgpr, if the [gRPC repository README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/core/lib/gpr) is to be believed.

Comment: @Botje I searched for the symbols in libgpr.a, and they seem to be there!

`readelf -Ws /path/to/package/libgpr.a | grep 'gpr_free'` returns `FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 gpr_free`.

So, I need to figure out why are these symbols not linked properly then...

Comment: The [conanfile](https://github.com/inexorgame/conan-grpc/blob/testing/1.23.0/conanfile.py#L144) seems to mention a dependency on gpr, so how does your project consume the conan package information (if at all)?

Comment: It doesn't :D Sorry, pretty new at conan stuff. Mind explaining, or sharing some link, apropos doing that?

Comment: Take a look at the existing [integrations](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations.html) or the [getting started](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) page that walks you through using the CMake generator.

Comment: Will do, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Conan, but gpr_* symbols are defined in libgpr. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L854

Comment: please, open an issue directly to the author: https://github.com/inexorgame/conan-grpc

Comment: @uilianries I did, it says in the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was that I was linking against libgrpc, but not against its dependencies!

Eventually, I modified my `CMakeLists.txt` to look like (don't ask me why it wasn't like that from the start...):

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CONAN_LIBS}
)
```

And then it built sucessfully.